# Laravel relationship between three table using ORM

Tags: orm, relationship, laravel-6

Here are my db table design. in my expense table has two foreign key which is connected to project table and category table. I want to show category name in my project Model . how can i make a relation between this tables???

**Note: Only expense table have foreign key[pro_id from project and cat_id from expense_category]**

[expense Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RURy9.png)

[image: expense category table]
[image: projects Table]
[image]

Comment: If you want to connect the Category and Project via Expanse, you need a many to many between the Project and Category.

Comment: @RobBiermann I want to connect projects_expense and category with Project... Suppose I want to show projects data & while doing that I need to show the related expense & category for individual project that's the idea. Now I can do that easily using normal sql but would like to learn Eloquent that's why I'm stuck in here. Help is appreciable.